# vimrc tags option specification for .git/tags files

Tags: vim, ctags

I'm using the following method to populate a tags file in my repositories' .git directories:

https://tbaggery.com/2011/08/08/effortless-ctags-with-git.html

So, for any given git repo, I will have a `.git/tags` file in it. How do I configure my `tags` option to recursively look up from my current directories in a repo to find these tags files?

I currently have this:

```
set tags^=./.git/tags,*/.git/tags;~
```

As I understand it, that should look for `./.git/tags` and if it exists use that. Else, it will go up **one** directory and look for `.git/tags` there. Failing that, it will go up **two** directories, and so on, stopping once it hits my home directory (`~`).

That seemed to work until I had another git repository in the mix. What I find is that if I have two repos at $HOME like so:

```
~/my_repo_2910
~/my_repo
```

If I am in `~/my_repo`, things work fine. That is, tag resolutions happen via `~/my_repo/.git/tags`. However, if I'm in a subdirectory of `~/my_repo`, say `~/my_repo/dir`, then running my tag commands will resolve to files in `~/my_repo_2910`. I'm not sure how that is possible, but it is very dangerous for me to unexpectedly jump repos via my `:tag` lookups.

Clearly I'm not setting the `tags` option correctly. Can someone point out what I'm doing wrong.

---

Update

Knoble's answer works for me if I update my CentOS 7 vim to version 8 following the instructions here:
https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/21697/25433

Then his tags specification works for me fine.

Comment: I think i have similar settings, but have not encountered this. Very bizarre.

Comment: Actually, no. Remove the `*`—

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the recent fugitive updates, I had to fix my tags setup (fugitive no longer sets tags).

I have this line now:

```
set tags^=.git/tags;~
```

Note the lack of `*` wildcard

---

As sussed out in comments, there appears to be a difference between my version (8+ on macOS) and the OP version (7.4 RHEL)

Comment: @dbenknoble This seems to work from the top of the git repository, but not from subdirectories. For me anyway. Can you please confirm that this finds your .git/tags file when you cd into sub directories of your repo, open a vim session, and run the tag command?

Comment: @firebush just confirmed—yes, this works for me. (`cd subdir; vim; :tag sometag` worked as expected)

Comment: Interesting. Can you please post the output to "set tags"? (It looks like with ^= you are appending to something previously set.)

Comment: @firebush : `.git/tags;~,./tags,tags`

Comment: @dbenknoble Interesting. Your tags option works as well for me in my mac vim 8.0 environment but not on my RHEL 7 vim 7.4 setup. There seems to be a difference in behavior across those versions. In any case, thank you for sharing.

Comment: For those in my situation, I was able to get things to work on my CentOS 7 system by upgrading vim to version 8 following these instructions: https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/21697/25433. Then Knoble's answer works for me fine. Thank you @dbenknoble.